# Why is my SQL not working?

Tags: mysql, sql, vba

I'm executing this code in Access but it gives the following error:

> Cannot find file **PATH**\test3.mdb

I use the following SQL code:

```
SELECT * INTO test1_sql.test2 FROM test3.test4
```

`test3` is a table imported from an Access MDB database, and `test1` is a table from a linked MySQL server.

I have no idea why the code isn't working. I hope somebody can help me with this.

Comment: `FROM test3.test4` means `FROM db.table` so its looking for database `test3` which doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example query, it would be more useful to use better naming so we can get a better idea of what you are trying to do.

If I assume you want to insert column `test4` from table `test3` into column `test2` in table `test1`.

The correct query to use would be:

```
SELECT test4 INTO test1.test2 FROM test3
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is no database by the name of `test3`. In the query

```
SELECT * INTO test1_sql.test2 FROM test3.test4
                                   ^^^^^
                                    |||| represents the database.
```

You probably need to provide the correct name of your database to get this executed.

Answer (score -1):

`FROM test3.test4` means `FROM db.table` so its looking for **database `test3`** which doesn't exist.

You will have to change `test3.test4` to your source table(`db.test3`).

Comment: Looks like you copied the comment from  dan08(BTW I am not the downvoter)

Comment: Looks like someone misunderstood the meaning of comments by the meaning of answers.

Comment: @inetphantom Its not a complete answer. It points out an issue but offers no solution.